# Configure SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I tried to configure SQL Server 2008 Management Studio by using configure tools and configure the firewall, but when I connect using SQL Server an error occurs saying that you must configure or the name of local server is incorrect.

Comment: did you try connecting via ip directly, too? can you ping the server that the sql server is running on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write correct `Server Name` like **local\SQLEXPRESS**. You can find the the local host name by using command prompt. Open command prompt and use this syntax `hostname` press enter.

Comment: I wrote my hostename/sqlexpress but even that it didn't work i follow this video in this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1j6AO8TMDA  but i found i haven't sql services as he has i has got just sql server agent(sqlexpress),sql server(sqlexpress)